# Есть ли случаи, когда союз "и" в предложении выделяется запятыми с обеих сторон?

Tags: союзы, пунктуация

Помогите разрешить давний спор: может ли союз "и" быть окружён запятыми с обеих сторон?

Comment: _...может ли союз "и" быть окружён запятыми с обеих сторон?_ === Конечно.  Ведь после "и" может идти вводное слово, деепричастный оборот, придаточное предложение... См. примеры: http://search1.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&spd=&text=lexgramm&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&parent1=0&level1=0&lex1=%E8&gramm1=&sem1=&sem-mod1=sem&sem-mod1=sem2&flags1=bcomma%2Cacomma&m1=&parent2=0&level2=0&min2=1&max2=1&lex2=&gramm2=&sem2=&sem-mod2=sem&sem-mod2=sem2&flags2=&m2=

Comment: Ну надо заметить, что первый же пример имеет совершенно немыслимую пунктуацию. )))

Comment: _...первый же пример имеет совершенно немыслимую пунктуацию._ === Да видел я это. Но выковыривать из множества нормальных примеров такие откровенные ляпы -- сверх моих сил...

Comment: Ну хотя бы предупредить, что не всему можно верить.

Comment: Спасибо за ответы и примеры. Я бы однако хотел бы видеть правила, которые в русском языке очень точно определяют причины для запятые и для их отсутствия. Некоторые из приведённых случаев вызывают сомнения. Возьмём у примеру такое предложение и разберёмся почему там запятые. "На каникулах дети ходили на пляж, загорали и, несмотря на холодную воду, купались". Запятая после "и" - из-за водных слов. Перед "и" нет запятой, потому что это соединительный союз между членами предложения (сказуемыми).

Answer (score 3):

Союз не обособляется по своему смыслу. А запятыми окружен быть может по тысяче и одной причине, но запятые эти будут относиться не к союзу, а к тому, что стоит до и перед ним.

*Я это знаю, потому что читал, и, если нужно, найду примеры.*